# 一人だけ来ました　potential interpretations

Tags: usage, idioms

> 一人【ひとり】だけ来ました【きました】

is translated as

> only one person came

on page 6-14 of "Learn to Read in Japanese" by Lake and Ura.

Could this also be read as "he/she came alone?" or is there a phrase that is more suited to that purpose?

Comment: Please write answers in the answer box :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「一人{ひとり}**だけ**来{き}ました」

can only mean:

> "Only one person came."

It cannot mean "He/She came alone."  To mean that, we say:

> 「その人{ひと}は一人**で**来ました。」 or
>
> 「その人は一人**だけで**来ました。」

(I used 「その人」 because it is not common at all to use third-person pronouns in Japanese.)

To emphasize the "alone" part, we also often say:

> 「～～は**たった**一人**で**来ました。」